# Modelling MVC + JSP with UML

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, design-patterns, uml

I am new to Java Server Pages (**JSP**) but I am pretty used to Unified Modeling Language (**UML**).

I want to start to develop a Web Application that uses the **Design Pattern** Model–view–controller (**MVC**).

For instance I want to build the adequate UML architecture for the example given on this [**MVC + JSP Tutorial**.](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm)

This Tutorial builds a simple application and as the author describes, it is a "*web application is a Coffee advisor, the user will input the type of Coffee and get back some advise*"

By adequate UML architecture, I mean **Sequence Diagrams, Class Diagram, Package Diagrams etc**.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question could seem out of topic because UML is unfortunately always associated to Model Driven Development.
I mean that if you use Persistence annotations in your class diagram which would generate the code including Hibernate annotation and then the database from the code then UML can deal with MVC and not only with MDD.

This is strange but I prefer MVC to MDD because this is more realistic and save a lot of time at coding and deployment level. This is also better if you need multiple iterations between deliveries and requirement changes.

You have many tools which allows ORM but I think only Omondo has investigated the UML with ORM at object level oppose to the other tools more MDD oriented. I mean generate a database from a model using code generation while Omondo is only using Hibernate annotations and then let Hibernate to create the database. I prefer to use UML and Hibernate and not MDD to generate my Database because when using MDD once you have generated your database you can not change the code manually. Everything should be done at model level. This is too much constraints and sometimes impossible. Omondo and Hibernate allows me to change my code as many times as needed.